# wordpress multi language with arabic and spanish

Tags: wordpress, arabic, multilingual

I am coding a site at http://myclientwebsites.com/UnderProgress/henry-haddad/ its in english, now the client wanted me to add Spanish and Arabic. Arabic is a RTL site. What is best way of doing this as I already have english site. I see for arabic site the layout also inverts (left to right and vice versa) should i have a wordpress install for every language?

I checked hWPML plugin for wordpress is there any free plugin for same.
(http://wpml.org/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codex for this purpose. It has support for many languages.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilingual/

Comment: thanks for your instant reply. The first link says we need to install specific version of wordpress so its like I need to have 3 installs do we have anything so we can just have one install and change layout/content as I have already english.

Comment: then try for wp-multilingual...the second link